# What is the idiomatic way to copy a ZipEntry into a new ZipFile?

Tags: java, copy, zip, docx

I'm writing a tool to do some minor text replacement in a DOCX file, which is a zipped format. My method is to copy `ZipEntry` contents from entries in the original file into the modified file using a `ZipOutputStream`. For most DOCX files this works well, but occasionally I will encounter `ZipException`s regarding discrepancies between the contents I've written and the meta-information contained in the `ZipEntry` (usually a difference in compressed size).

Here's the code I'm using to copy over contents. I've stripped out error handling and document processing for brevity; I haven't had issues with the document entry so far.

```
ZipFile         original = new ZipFile(INPUT_FILENAME);
ZipOutputStream outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE));
Enumeration     entries = original.entries();
byte[]          buffer = new byte[512];
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry    entry = (ZipEntry)entries.nextElement();
    if  ("word/document.xml".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getName())) {
        //perform special processing
    }
    else{
        outputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
        InputStream in = original.getInputStream(entry);
        while (0 < in.available()){
            int read = in.read(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer,0,read);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    outputStream.closeEntry();
}
outputStream.close();
```

What is the proper or idiomatic way to directly copy `ZipEntry` objects from one `ZipFile` to another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a workaround that avoids the error. By creating a new `ZipEntry` with only the name field set I'm able to copy over contents without issue.

```
ZipFile         original = new ZipFile(INPUT_FILENAME);
ZipOutputStream outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILE));
Enumeration     entries = original.entries();
byte[]          buffer = new byte[512];
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry    entry = (ZipEntry)entries.nextElement();
    if  ("word/document.xml".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getName())) {
        //perform special processing
    }
    else{
        // create a new empty ZipEntry
        ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(entry.getName()); 
//      outputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
        outputStream.putNextEntry(newEntry);
        InputStream in = original.getInputStream(entry);
        while (0 < in.available()){
            int read = in.read(buffer);
            if (read > 0) {
              outputStream.write(buffer,0,read);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }
    outputStream.closeEntry();
}
outputStream.close();
```

However, I this method loses any meta-information stored in the fields of original `ZipEntry` (e.g.: comment, extra). The API docs aren't clear on whether this is important.

Comment: I've marked my workaround as the answer since there doesn't seem to be a better answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your meta-data for the zip entry, create it using ZipEntry's "copy constructor":

```
ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(entry);
```

You can then modify just the name or the comments etc. and everything else will be copied from the given `entry`.

You could also look at [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which can populate DocX files from Java.

Comment: Unfortunately the copy constructor suffers from my original problem, which is that the sizes copied over from the original have incorrect compressed sizes. My workaround avoids this by allowing the library to set sizes automatically, but with the downside of losing metadata. Docmosis looks like a great service, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It suffices to add one more line: `newEntry.setCompressedSize(-1);`, and it works.

Comment: No need to set compressed size to -1 as constructor sets that value by default. I guess that the copying to a new entry works because it forces recalculation of all values and fixes size and compressed size. The size exception happened when the zip file contains a compressed file such as a tar file.