# Rename file inside zip in Java

Tags: java, zip, rename, zipoutputstream

Now I've got a zip file (Dice.zip), inside the zip is a folder(Dice/..) and I want to modify some of the files inside that folder then rename the folder. I've managed to modify the files and rename the zip(from Dice.zip to DiceUp.zip) but when I unzip the file (DiceUp.zip) I get the folder (Dice/..) not (DiceUp/..). Any Idea how to rename the folder?

Comment: How did you create the file in the first place?  What API are you using to unzip?

Comment: This is what I've done so far
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645153/error-java-util-zip-zipexception-invalid-entry-size-while-copying-image-png/37645519#37645519

Comment: Have you looked in truezip (https://truezip.java.net/), would be lot easier to manipulate zip files